# Mysql Queries in big data table

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, innodb

I have problem with my mysql database table. I have more then 20 millions rows in table. Table structure shown below. Main problem is that queries take really long time to execute (some queries take more then 20 second). I use indexes where i can, however many queries use date range and with date range my indexes don't work. Also in queries i use almost every column. What i need to change to my data table, to improve efficiency?

```
`history` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `barcode` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bag` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `action` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `place` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `old_price` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rotation` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `discount` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `discount_type` tinyint(2) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `original` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `was_in_shop` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `cate` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'grupe',
  `sub_cate` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `helper` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ywd` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
)

PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `barcode` (`barcode`) USING BTREE,
KEY `action` (`action`) USING BTREE,
KEY `original` (`original`) USING BTREE,
KEY `created_at` (`created_at`) USING BTREE,
KEY `bag` (`bag`) USING BTREE

ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Some of my queries:

```
select SUM(amount) as amount, 
       SUM(comment) as price, 
       cate 
  from `history` 
 where (    `action` = '4' 
        and `place` = '28' 
        and `created_at` >= '2018-04-01 00:00:00'
        and `created_at` <= '2018-04-30 23:59:59'
       ) 
   and `history`.`deleted_at` is null 
group by `cate`;

select cate, 
       SUM(amount) AS kiekis, 
       SUM(IF(discount>0,(price*amount)-discount,(price*amount))) AS suma, 
       SUM(IF(discount>0,IF(discount_type=1,(discount*price)/100,discount),0)) AS nuolaida 
  from `history` 
 where (    `history`.`action` = '4' 
        and `history`.`created_at` >= '2018-01-01 00:00:00'
        and `history`.`created_at` <= '2018-01-23 23:59:59'
       ) 
   and LENGTH(barcode) > 7
   and `history`.`deleted_at` is null 
 group by `cate`;
```

Comment: pls. show the query in the post too

Comment: We will need to know what sort of queries you are having problems with to be able to give any meaningful guidance.  I am going to take a guess that you never use the `id` in queries, and this is just a surrogate key?  If this is the case then you might consider making `id` a unique constraint instead, and changing your primary key to something that will help more when pulling data back out.  The primary key defines what order the data is physically stored in (clustered index), so if you are always querying by barcode then it might make more sense to use this as the primary key instead?

Comment: Added some of my queries to post. I can't use barcode as my primary, because i have multiple rows with same barcode.

Comment: show us the `explain` plan, try other indexes, virtual column index on LENGTH(barcode), or an index on the deleted_at column, or maybe add a flag column IsDeleted as boolean instead of testing null/not null values and have an index with a lot of values

Answer (score 1):

Your first query is better written as:

```
select SUM(h.amount) as amount, 
       SUM(h.comment) as price, 
       h.cate 
from history h
where h.action = 4 and 
      h.place = 28 and
      h.created_at >= '2018-04-01' and
      h.created_at < '2018-05-01' and
      h.deleted_at is null 
group by h.cate;
```

Why?

- `place` and `action` are numbers.  The comparison should be to a number.  Mixing types can prevent the use of indexes.
- The time component is not useful for the date comparison.
- Qualifying all columns names is just a good idea.

Then, for this query, a reasonable index is `history(action, place, created_at, deleted_at)`.

So, I would start with multi-column indexes.

If you continue to have performance issues, you should then consider partitioning the data based on the `created_at` date.

Answer (score 1):

`INDEX(a), INDEX(b)` serves some purposes, but the "composite" `INDEX(a,b)` better serves some queries.

```
 where (    `action` = '4' 
        and `place` = '28' 
        and `created_at` >= '2018-04-01 00:00:00'
        and `created_at` <= '2018-04-30 23:59:59'
       ) 
   and `history`.`deleted_at` is null
```

Needs

```
INDEX(action, place, -- first, but in either order
      deleted_at,
      created_at)    -- last
```

I prefer to write the date range thus:

```
        and `history`.`created_at` >= '2018-04-01'
        and `history`.`created_at`  < '2018-04-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

It's a lot easier than dealing with leap year, end of year, etc.  And it works 'correctly' for `DATE`, `DATETIME`, `DATETIME(6)`, `TIMESTAMP`, and `TIMESTAMP(6)`.

For this

```
 where (    `history`.`action` = '4' 
        and `history`.`created_at` >= '2018-01-01 00:00:00'
        and `history`.`created_at` <= '2018-01-23 23:59:59'
       ) 
   and LENGTH(barcode) > 7
   and `history`.`deleted_at` is null
```

I would try this as the most likely:

```
INDEX(action, deleted_at, created_at)  -- in this order
```

Do *not* have separate tables for separate years.  If you will be deleting old data, then consider `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(...))` in order to get the speed of `DROP PARTITION`.  (But that is another discussion.)

Answer (score -1):

If I was in your situation I would consider a paged database name. By this I mean have multiple history_X tables where X is an int related to the content.

Since this is a history table is it possible to include part of the date in the name?

You said that you use ranges to search for the data, so if you were to use year in the table name you could have

- history_2014
- history_2015
- history_2016
- history_2017
- history_2018
- etc.

Then you could search with the table that applies to your date range.

If you need date from a range that spans to tables then you could use a UNION query to bridge the 2 result sets into one.

Comment: my history table contains only one year data, i already have separated older data to different tables

Comment: This is extremely bad advice.  Splitting a table into multiple different tables is a bad, bad idea.